# "formatter doesn't support the nested 'param' element" error with PMD Ant task

Tags: ant, pmd

I'm using Ant 1.9.4.

When I run the following target:

```
<presetdef name="pmd.scan">
    <pmd rulesetfiles="${root.dir}/scripts/pmd5_rules.xml" minimumPriority="${pmd.minimum.priority}">
        <formatter type="xml" toFile="${pmd.report.xml}" showSuppressed="true">
            <param name="linePrefix" value=".line"/>
        </formatter>
        <fileset refid="pmd.files"/>
        <sourceLanguage name="java" version="1.8"/>
    </pmd>
</presetdef>
```

I end up with **formatter doesn't support the nested "param" element.** How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested `<param>` elements under `<formatter>` were added to [PMD 5.0.0](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.3/changelog-old.html#January_31_2012_-_5.0-alpha:) in 2012:

> Ant changes: Removed -  'linePrefix' attribute, use `<param name="linePrefix">` instead

Make sure you're using at least version 5.0.0 of PMD.

Comment: Thank you @Chad . After updating to latest PMD its got resolved.